# How to preserve last page when using back button with react-router?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I’m doing a redirect from within a component’s render like this:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import browserHistory from "react-router/lib/browserHistory";

class LoginRedirectExample extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  }

  redirectToLogin() {
    browserHistory.push("/login”);
    return null;
  }

  render () {
    return (
       <div className={c("container")}>
        {
          this.props.isLoggedIn ? this.redirectToLogin() : <button>Click Me</button>
        }
       </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Works great - but when if I’m redirected to the login view - I can’t use the browser back button - it doesn’t do anything. 
How do I handle this redirect and still have the functionality of the back button with react router?
I’m using react-router 3 if that makes a difference.

Comment: Not sure. I think the functionality must be working. When you press the  back button you come to the same screen which again checking for logged in prop pushes back the login screen.

Comment: Is it possible that you have an issue somewhere else in your application? You may want to debug by consoling window.history and the browserHistory object.

Comment: You can use the history object that comes as props to the component if you have set up initial routing for your app. It id not necessary to import browserHistory in every component, doing that may cause the history object to be overwritten, which would not preserve your last route and hence you cannot go back.

Comment: @eshunsharma can you provide an example?

Comment: Please refer this article to setup initial app/routing. https://blog.pshrmn.com/simple-react-router-v4-tutorial/ Once that is done you can easily access history from props.